# LTE Router vs Mobile hotspot (Android) - Opening ports

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding, android

I'm trying to host a publicly accessible website over a mobile hotspot (Android).

I've managed to access the page from another device connected to the same network. but when I tried apps on the Play Store to port forward traffic from my phone's public IP to my desired IP, nothing happens.

I'm quite sure that the LTE provider does not block access to the port. Using the SIM card in an LTE router, like the [TP-Link Archer MR200](http://www.tp-link.com/eg/products/details/cat-4691_Archer-MR200.html), I was able to perform port forwarding and access my website through the public IP.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is very unlikely you will be able to port forward ports on a LTE router/gateway in order to have st a website on the connection.  Your ip address wouldnt be static.

Comment: @Ramhound I use No-IP to solve the problem of not having a static ip address.

Comment: So does this modem/gateway actually have a port forwarding configuration page?

Comment: Yes, it functions similarly to a normal broadband router. i.e. admin options at 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1. As mentioned in my question, I have successfully accessed the website from the internet hosted on a device connected to the router.

Comment: Have you actually checked with the LTE provider for confirmation?

Comment: @Burgi Nope, but I don't need to, do I? The port can be forwarded with the use of a router, as mentioned.